# With Delphi Indy 10.6 and tcpclient is there any way to tell the data format in the input buffer

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy

I'm transferring small byte packets and file streams.  Is there any way to tell if the incoming packet is actually a file stream or does it all just look like bytes to the IOHandler?

Comment: Send the data type information as well then.

Comment: I know what I'm expecting, but if things get "out of sync", knowing what type of data is waiting for me would be really helpful.

Comment: Your client should know that. There cannot be any "out of control" behavior. If the client doesn't know the kind of stuff your server serves them, it should tell it as well. And then the client will be waiting either until the file transfer is completed (e.g. by sending the file transfer is about to happen followed by the file size bytes), or receive bytes until some terminating packet is received.

Comment: @Skutch "*if things get "out of sync", knowing what type of data is waiting for me would be really helpful*". If you use a properly designed protocol, and are sending and reading packets correctly, you will never get of of sync, unless the sender sends garbage to begin with, or there is a network error. In which case, all you can usually do is just close the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell if the incoming packet is actually a file stream or does it all just look like bytes to the IOHandler?

It is just raw bytes as far as the IOHandler is concerned. It is your responsibility to define and implement a protocol in your application code to control how data packets are structured and identified.  For instance, TLD (Type-Length-Data) is a common protocol idiom, where a value identifies the type of data being sent, followed by a value containing the length of the data, followed by the actual data.